# Equivalent definitions of suspension of simplicial set.

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

For a pointed simplicial set $X$, the suspension $\Sigma X$ is calculated as the smash product $S^1\wedge X$, where $S^1=\Delta^1/\partial\Delta^1$. In the literature, there is another definition: $\Sigma X$ is calculated as the the homotopy cofiber of the canonical map $X\rightarrow *$.

Why these two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: I don't know much but I can say that $\Sigma X:=S^1\wedge X$ is the general definition for (pointed) spaces $X$.

Comment: Equivalent in what sense? They are weakly homotopy equivalent, sure.

Comment: I'm not sure in what sense, because the literature just said equivalently(e.g. A primer of unstable motivic homotoyp theory, after proposition 4.36). I guess this means homotopy equivalent.